# How to check if glBufferData with NULL has completed and if glMapBuffer won't block on it?

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to allocate a fairly large buffer (`1 GB`) for a PBO on application startup, and do it like so:

`glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, new_size, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);`

I need to map the buffer (with `glMapBuffer`) shortly afterwards, in order to start writing data to it.
The problem is, if I call `glMapBuffer` right after `glBufferData`, **it blocks**, because it must wait for the allocation to complete. Thus I'd like to have a way to query if `glMapBuffer` can now return immediately, or if it would still block, so that my application can do something else in the meantime.

The funny thing is, fence objects seem to be signaled immediately after the call to `glBufferData`, so they don't seem to tell me anything useful.

Even if I do

```
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, new_size, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glFinish();
glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
```

It is the call to `glMapBuffer` that stalls, not `glFinish`. Same thing about `glFlush`.

**How do I know if the buffer - for which no data was specified - has finished allocation and is ready to be mapped?**

Comment: "*so that my application can do something else in the meantime*" If you have some other task you could be doing, you should just do that task and come back to it later.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find in the specifications when `glBufferData` may return. I guess it's a vendor decision based on the given parameters for the buffer.

But I find at [OGL 4.6 spec. 6.3 Mapping ...](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> If no error occurs, a pointer to the beginning of the mapped range is
>   returned once all pending operations on that buffer have completed

Because allocating the required size likely is a pending operation, then the CPU will wait until `glMapBuffer` returns.

Also in the spec, 2.3.3 Flush and Finish:

> **Finish** does not return until all effects from such commands on GL
>   client and server state and the framebuffer are fully realized.

Notice that it tells about *states* and the framebuffer, not about any other buffer. So, there's no enforcement for `glFinish` to wait for a buffer to be allocated.

---

What I would do in your case is to put all of first buffer creation and initialization in a thread. In this thread, right after `glMapBuffer` returns, send a message (or change some flag) to the app meaning "Pointer to unpack data to GPU is ready".

The data upload may be done in a different thread. Don't forget to set the gl-context as current to the thread that calls gl-commands.